# Form - Accessing submitted/bound data

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony

Imagine this form

```php
class CarType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('brand', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:CarBrand',
                'label' => 'Brand',
            ))
            ->add('model', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:CarModel',
                'label' => 'Car model',
                'choices' => array(),                // <- Depends on brand
            ));
        // ...
    }
}
```

I used some ajax to make the `model` list depending on `brand` selection.

I didn't use `FormEvents` because it was a real pain in the ass for my simple need (I have actually 3 dependencies based on multiple parameters and I already spent an entire day trying to figure out how to make it work with `FormEvents`)

Now, once the form is submitted, I want to get the bound values from my controller.

```
/**
 * @Route("/context", name="context_selection")
 */
public function carSelectionAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(CarType::class, new Car());
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        $car = $form->getData();
        dump($car);                                 // <- Getting only brand here
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle::car-selection.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

The dumped data is showing only the `CarBrand` object bound, I imagine because the selected `CarModel` is not a valid choice.

**How can I get the bound `CarModel` ?**

*I'd rather not having to read the request params and load the objects myself*

Comment: Use data transformers. [Cookbook: Transforming an Issue Number into an Issue Entity](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#harder-example-transforming-an-issue-number-into-an-issue-entity) and have your js-code submit the entity-id as a form field.